# Click not working in any condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just a simple hyperlink on which when I am trying to add an `click()` event handler it is not working. I tried, `.on(), .live(), .delegate()` none of them worked. How can I do it?

*I cannot make a fiddle becuase I don't know why my bootstrap.min.css is not getting included in the **external resources** section.*

Please tell me any other way of doing it.

**My Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar nav-fixed-top navbar-inverse" style="min-height: 50px; margin-bottom: 0; box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #222;">
    <!-- Creating a fixed to the top navbar with no bottom margin and a nice little shadow and increasing the height -->
    <div class="navbar-inner" style="border-radius: 0;min-height: 50px; ">
        <!-- Creating the inner content of navbar and increasng it's height aswell to match the parent's height aswell -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Main header starts -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <!-- Small screen collapseable menu starts -->  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <!-- The collapseable menu icon(becuase the three `icon-bar` make an icon :P) -->
            </button>   <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"
                    style="height: 25px;" /> </a> 
            <!-- adding the logo to the header -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
                <!-- div holding collapseable menu's data -->
                <ul class="nav">
                    <!-- creating a list to be created in the collapseable menu -->
                    <li><a href="#" id="register_button">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- adding an hyper link to the collapseable menu -->
                </ul>
                <!-- closing the list -->
            </div>
            <!-- closing the div holding collapseable menu's data -->
        </div>
        <!-- closing the main header -->
    </div>
    <!-- closing inner content holder of navbar div -->
</div>
<!-- closing the fixed to top navbar holder -->
```

**CSS:** *Using bootstrap.min.css*

**JS:**

```
var registerBtn = $("#register_button"); //storing the hyperlink of register in a variable
var i = 0; //click count
$(registerBtn).on('click', function (e) {
    i++;
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
            $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast');
        });
        $("#register").text('Register');
    } else {
        $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
            $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast');
        });
        $("#register").text('Login');
    }
});
```

Any suggesstions?

Comment: Remove the jQuery wrapper around `$(registerBtn)`

Comment: If that JavaScript code is *before* the HTML with your button, then nothing will happen. You can put it in a "ready" handler or move it to the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: @Sergio didn't worked.

Comment: prevent default behaviour of anchor link clicked: `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Pointy didn't worked and A.Wolff didn't worked aswell :'(

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui it should if you define 'e' as argument function. BTW, is `console.log(registerBtn.length)` returning 1 ?

Comment: @Sergio Worked!!! Thanks. Make it an answer and get it accepted. :)

Comment: It works - have noone tried? The click event is fired

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui not possible, Sergio's answer just remove an useless wrapping but this not affect behaviour in any way

Comment: I think Sergio meant changing `$(registerBtn).on(...` to `registerBtn.on(...`.

Comment: @A.Wolff - the link does not have a URL.  It does not require `preventDefault()`

Comment: Still a good idea to use preventDefault() to stop the jump.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, the jQuery wrapper should not be the solution check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ePVFe/1/ - did you also add the .ready wrapper? maybe that was what made it work?

Comment: yeah! that's right @Sergio ! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code :

```
$(function() {
    var registerBtn = $("#register_button"); //storing the hyperlink of reg....

    var i = 0; //click count

    registerBtn.on('click', function (e) { // since registerBtn is a reference to anchor tag
        e.prevenDefault(); // prevent default behaviour of anchor tag
        .........
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably executing the handler binding **before** the element is created in the DOM. Either move the code to the end of the document (after the element has been created), or wrap it inside a ready event:

```
$(function() {
    var registerBtn = $("#register_button"); //storing the hyperlink of register in a variable
    var i = 0; //click count
    $(registerBtn).on('click', function (e) {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
                $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast');
            });

    $("#register").text('Register');
        } else {
            $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
                $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast');
            });
            $("#register").text('Login');
        }
    });
});
```